# Java Implement @SuppressWarnings("unused")

Tags: java, annotations

I have a custom annotation processor, and I'd like one of my annotations to have the same effect as @SuppressWarnings("unused"). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What's the reason for using a custom annotation rather than just `@SuppressWarnings`?

Comment: Because the custom annotation implies that the method will be unused.